# Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (ODT)

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, odt, schema-compare

I have created an Oracle Database Project Version 2 on visual studio 2017 and imported an existing database to the project to obtain the database schema on my project, and I got an SQLfile for such object in my project. The problem is when I'm modifying a table for example and saving the changes on my oracle database project and build it, I get a create script as output instead of an alter script so this script can't be deployed to my database due to "existing object error".

I tried to do it otherwise by proceeding to schema compare option:

- I launched the schema comparison by mentionning my oracle database project as source and my database as target
- The result of the comparison indicated that there is an non indentical object between the source and the target which was the table (because i added a coloumn to the table)

Again the problem is when I generate the update script it gives a drop/create table script instead of an alter and I can't deploy this script because I will lose data.

Does anyone have any ideas? how can I get the alter script by building the project or launching a schema compare operation?

Comment: What kind of objects you try to update?

Comment: I added a column to an existing table

Comment: I have always the same problem I made a lot or researchs but with no resuls. If anyone knows something concernig this issue and can help me to resolve it, I will be greatfull.

Comment: Are you not able to write the `ALTER TABLE` commands by yourself?

Comment: I'm using a database project with  the ODT tool which is suposed to detect the changes between the source and the target and generate a diff script. This script can be deployed on a database. I should not dot it by myself cauz it's the utility of this kind of projects.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that comparing two databases DO generate a "somewhat" correct diff script (it may need some manual adjustment). So you can run the SQL file generated by the database project against a different oracle instance, and then compare both.